# Excel, assigning text a number and summing them

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am making a recipe spreadsheet.  What I have is an amount column and a measurements column.   For example an amount of 1 and a measurement of cup (for a 1 cup measurement), an amount of 4 and a measurement of tbsp (for a 4 tbsp measurement).

[image]

What I've been trying to do is make the text cup become a number 1, make the text tsp become a number 1/48, and make the text tbsp become a number 1/16.
Then, I would like to sum all the numerical values of cup, tbsp, tsp in the measurement column multiplied by their corresponding amount in the amount column, so that I can get a total in cups of all the ingredients.
I've tried defining the name cup=1, etc and setting the column values as numbers, but cannot sum them.

You would rock my world if you can lead me in the right direction.  I'm more a noob in Excel, so explanations would be awesome with very baby steps.  I might not even know where to find commands and certain tabs or options.

Comment: Just so you don't question why the formula doesn't match the physical results, most recipes that include different powdered ingredients, and both powdered and wet ingredients, will take less total space combined than the sum of the component volumes (your "total in cups" won't match the volume of the mixture).  Other than that, a nice Excel question.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

You would create a table with the conversions:

[image]

Then you simply use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$2:$C$14*(LOOKUP($D$2:$D$14,$H$2:$H$4,$I$2:$I$4)))
```

OR this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF($H$2:$H$4,$D$2:$D$14,$I$2:$I$4)*$C$2:$C$14)
```

[image]

---

Another method is to use a helper column.  In E2 put:

```
=C2*VLOOKUP(D2,$H$2:$I$4,2)
```

Then copy down.  Then a simple `=SUM(E2:E14)`

[image]

Comment: *(love that helper column +1)*

Comment: @Gary'sStudent was just about to put up a comment saying how I had to put that in there just for you.